# Jquery - open popup, fill textbox and then submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to find a way to open a popup window with a textfield to enter a value before the form is submitted.

Basically, user clicks on 'Submit', it opens a popup asking with a textfield to enter a value and then submits the whole thing to the next page.

I am a little confused on how to achieve this. I am using classic ASP and JQuery.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var text = prompt("Enter your something here:");
if(text){ // text was entered
    // Submit process here and use
    // text
    // as the variable containing the user message
}
```

[jsBin example](http://jsbin.com/sotuyece/1/edit)

```
$("#myForm").submit(function( e ){
  e.preventDefault();
  var text = prompt("Enter your something here:");
  if(text){
      alert("User entered: "+ text);
  }else{
      // Do something
  }
});
```